# iOS UIScrollView. Making a screen whose contents are longer than storyboard screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I need to make a vertically scrolling screen, because the items I want to display take up more vertical real estate than an iPhone screen. The same limitation seems to apply to storyboard, where I am finding it very difficult to design my screen because of the limited size of the view.

1. The contents of the screen I am trying to design are longer than the iPhone, storyboard is preventing me from designing the entirety of the screen even though I am using a scrollview as the root view. How do I get around this?

Answer (score 0):

what I do is I drag the UIScrollView up and then extend it and add whatever I need to, to it. And then when I am done working with it, I put it back in place.

Answer (score 0):

You probably can't do much with the mouse, but try setting the height of the scrollview.  You should be able to set the bounds of individual sub elements.  You can manually scroll the view by setting properties.

You won't be able to see what the full screen looks like in Xcode, you'll have to run it.

Alternatively, you can design it for the normal height, but with constraints so that it goes to the real location when you run it